# Why won't my decimal to binary output reverse?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I am doing some simple decimal to binary conversion using a while loop, and I realized that my output from the loop needs to be reversed, which i did so by creating a stringstream and then moving my generated int into a stringstream which then converts it to a string and then reverses the order for the string to get the correct binary value... but when I actually run the code, there's like a random 1 or 0 out in front of everything...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    int decimal;
    int binary;
    std::cout<< "\n Please enter decimal value: ";
    std::cin >> decimal;
    std::cout << "\n The binary equivalent of " << decimal << " is ";
    while(decimal > 0 ) {
        binary = decimal % 2;

        decimal/= 2;

        std::cout << binary;

    }
    ss << binary;
    std::string binary_string = ss.str();
    std::reverse(binary_string.begin(), binary_string.end());
    std::cout << binary_string;
}
```

For example, if I input an 11 I get this:

```
Please enter decimal value: 11

The binary equivalent of 11 is 11011
```

For 12:

```
Please enter decimal value: 12

The binary equivalent of 12 is 00111
```

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra bit is coming from

```
ss << binary;
string binary_string = ss.str();
reverse(binary_string.begin(), binary_string.end());
cout << binary_string;
```

after the loop.  `binary` is either going to contain a `1` or a `0` and converting that to string and reversing it is going to give you the same thing.  You need to move `ss << binary;` into the loop so it contains all the binary digits you generate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. The line `ss << binary` should be put inside the loop
2. You should remove `cout << binary` from the loop

It would look like that

```
int decimal;
int binary;
cout<< "\n Please enter decimal value: ";
cin >> decimal;
cout << "\n The binary equivalent of " << decimal << " is ";
while(decimal > 0 ) {
    binary = decimal % 2;

    decimal/= 2;
    ss << binary;

}

string binary_string = ss.str();
reverse(binary_string.begin(), binary_string.end());
cout << binary_string;

}
```